# MonoMac Could Not Load Assembly or Dependency

Tags: c#, macos, monomac

I have a fairly simple application that I built using MonoDevelop 3.0/XCode 4.0/.NET 4.0 on OS X 10.7 (Lion). Basically, I have a Windows GUI and a Mac GUI for the application, and both share a class library. The class library is very simple (deliberately), and passes the MoMA tests with flying colors. My OS X GUI runs perfectly on my development OS X machine, but when I create a .pkg file and install it on a test OS X machine, it won't run at all. I have the Mono runtime installed on the test machine -- the runtime only, not the SDK or MonoDevelop. The application will open, but as soon as I make a call into the shared library, it fails with

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xxx' or one of its dependencies.

My shared library only has the following dependencies:

- System
- System.Configuration
- System.Core
- System.Xml.Linq
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
- Microsoft.CSharp
- System.Data
- System.Xml

Surely the basic Mono framework supports all of these assemblies, right? What am I missing? I can't believe that releasing a simple application like this (via .pkg file, not AppStore) is so difficult! Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: In the past, I successfully created a MonoMac pkg file. So it *is* possible.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is possible. I created a .pkg file for an app that did NOT have any external references, and it worked fine. The question is, did you successfully release a MonoMac pkg file that references a class library created somewhere else? Did it access data? Did it have any of the same dependencies as what I listed? Just saying you did it isn't really helping much...sorry.

Comment: Actually, IIRC, I've created the class library directly inside MonoDevelop. And it only uses .NET 2 features. Maybe you should investigate in the *"...or one of its dependencies..."* part and get the details of which dependencies the error is talking?

Comment: Well, maybe that's my problem: I built the class library in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7, and then referenced it in MonoDevelop. I ran the assembly through the MoMA analyzer, and it said it's fine, but apparently it's not. The only place I know to look for errors is in the Apple System Log (ASL), and it doesn't tell me which dependency is causing the problem. Is there a better place to look?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've just searched Google for "could not load file or assembly monomac" but found no relevant hits. Maybe you could ask on some MonoMac forum/list how/whether to enable fusion log in MonoMac? (or are there maybe already more details when inspecting the exception you get?)

Comment: Thanks, Uwe. See my solution below. Was much more basic than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so, total noob/forehead slapping moment: the reason my application ran on my development OS X environment but not on the test box? .NET framework! I built the class library with Visual Studio 2012/.NET 4.5/Windows 7, checked it with MoMA, then copied it to my dev OS X, set a reference to it in my MonoMac project, and everything was fine, right? That's because that box had MonoDevelop and the .NET framework on it! When I created my .pkg and installed it on a new OS X box, the install was smart enough to download and install the Mono environment, but not the .NET framework, and who can blame it? The solution: build the class library against Mono 4.0, and use *that* assembly in my MonoMac release! Problem solved.

Thanks for help and comments. Please forgive the basic stupidity of this question: I'm not only a Mono/OS X noob, I'm a desktop development noob, too. I'm a web guy, for cryin' out loud!